# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:

Tags: apex

I am new to salesforce. I was trying to update that account record name belong to me. I am getting

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

could some can help me here is my class

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;
    public Account ER;

    ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller;

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       GstdController=controller;
       this.ER= (Account)controller.getRecord();
       this.stdController = controller;

    }

    public PageReference Save() {
        system.debug('Save::::1111');
        String rType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
        system.debug('sc::::'+rType);
        this.ER.RecordTypeId = rType;

        PageReference pr= stdController.save();
        //insert ER;
         pr.setRedirect(false);
         system.debug('Save::::2222');

        return pr;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the error - the debug log should tell you. I am wondering if the   String rType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType'); is throwing an error?

Comment: iam getting on pr.setRedirect (false); line

Comment: Seems like there is an error on safe and thus it is returning a null page reference. Check for Page Message to see what the issue is

Comment: I'm with Eric - execute the save with a try/catch, and then redirect if the save is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, whenever you use getRecord() method, it does not mean it will load all the Account property except if the properties are defined in Visual Force Page example  {!RecordTypeId} .

Can you try retrieve Account record including RecordTypeId then update it with the one that you retrieve from parameter?

Something like this:

```
this.ER =[Select Id,RecordTypeId from Account where Id =: controller.getId()]
this.ER.RecordTypeId = recType;//get this from parameter

//then update code
```

Hope it help.

Thanks